# Where can I get a TopoJSON with 3 digit zip codes (zip3) shapes?

Tags: zip-codes, topojson

Where can I get a TopoJSON file with 3 digit zip codes (zip3) shapes

I have searched for days and I just can find 5 digit zip codes shapes.

Comment: or you could dissolve your 5-digit ZIP code polygons by the first 3 numbers.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: what GIS software do you have at your disposal?

Comment: None. I'm just trying to make a d3 colored map with some data. I'm more a front end code guy than a GIS guy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this link: https://www.baruch.cuny.edu/confluence/display/geoportal/ESRI+USA+Data

There is a link to ZIP3 Shapefiles.

As for how to convert to topojson, try Mike Bostock's tools: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson

Comment: Thanks I downloaded the zip file: it has a shp, dbf & shx files inside. Still trying to convert them to a topojsoon one.

Comment: are you using Mike Bostock's tools? I added a link above...

Comment: I was using that for mixing some csv data to the topojson I had about US States. Your comment made me check the docs and yes: there's a converter from shapefile to topojson.

So, for future reference here are the steps:
1.Download the zip3 file here http://www.vdstech.com/usa-data.aspx (It's a zip containing .shp .dbx & .shx files)
2.Install topojson in the command line https://github.com/mbostock/topojson
3. Covert the file and remember to add the data in the .dbx using "-p"

topojson -o output.json -p -- zip3.shp

Comment: @earlyriser good stuff!

Comment: Anyone know if there's another source for this data? The website appears to no longer exist. If you happen to have it that would be great if you could post it in another link, thanks!

Comment: found it here: https://www.baruch.cuny.edu/confluence/display/geoportal/ESRI+USA+Data

Comment: @clhenrick thanks, I updated the link in the answer...!

Answer (score 0):

Download the shapefiles for zip3 from here:
[Github Repo for zip3 shapefiles](https://github.com/gweissman86/three_digit_zips)

To convert to geojson/topojson refer:
[Convert shapefiles to geojson/topojson](https://www.statsilk.com/maps/convert-esri-shapefile-map-geojson-format)